# Rutas en Wordpress - Ruta de Páginas no funcionan

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Tengo un problema con las páginas de wordpress, mas exactamente en las rutas de estas.

Acabo de crear algunas páginas, nada complicado, una etiqueta  y una

Al darle vista previa funciona perfectamente, no hay error ni nada por ese estilo,

El problema surge cuando publico la pagina, por ejemplo coloco la ruta de la página  **Test3**, la publico y de la ruta aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

después de publicarlo deja de funcionar la vista previa, puedo seguir modificarlo pero no ver ni publicarlo porque falla completamente.

PD:
Acabo de copiar el proyecto a otro servidor, cambie el dominio en la bd manualmente, pensé que quizás fuera eso, no funcionó.

PD:
Modifique el .htaccess por el defecto de wordpress, no funciono

Comment: feyesmanizales es el nuevo dominio? por lo general en nueva instalación luego de una mudanza tenés que ir a settings -> permalinks y darle save permalinks para que refresque el asunto, otra opción es que no tengas activado el soporte de  `.htaccess` en el nuevo servidor ( `AllowOverride All` en una sección `Directory` )

Comment: Alo, Puedes colocar tu comentario como respuesta, si, ese es el nuevo dominio y tienes razón, AllowOverride  estaba desactivado, eres un grande crack, muchas gracias!!!!!!!

¡Gracias Totales!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique que

```
AllowOverride All
```

Esté habilitado en el [`server.conf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride), si no, por favor habilítelo y reinicie apache, con esto ya las rutas deberian funcionar, si no es así, por favor reescriba el .htaccess presente en la raíz de su proyecto de wordpress, para hacerlo puede encontrar el valor predeterminado aquí

https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/